# How to verify a ECC signature with OpenSSL command?

Tags: command-line, openssl, ecdsa

I have a public key, a 192 bit hash, and a 384 bit signature, all as .txt hex files, and the curve is prime192v1.

What command lines can I use to verify the message with OpenSSL?

Answer (score 5):

For reference, the EC key can be created with the following command:

- Create the EC key:

  ```
  $ openssl ecparam -genkey -name prime192v1 > key.pem
  ```
- Extract the public key:

  ```
  $ openssl ec -in key.pem -pubout > pub.pem
  ```

Signing the hash of a message and verifying the signature with an EC key can be done the same way as with other key types:

- Calculate the hash (use a hash funtion of your choice):

  ```
  $ openssl dgst -sha256 -binary message.txt > hash.txt
  ```
- Sign the hash with the private key:

  ```
   $ openssl pkeyutl -sign -inkey key.pem -in hash.txt > sig.txt
  ```
- Verify the signature with the public key:

  ```
   $ openssl pkeyutl -verify -in hash.txt -sigfile sig.txt -inkey pub.pem -pubin
   Signature Verified Successfully
  ```

Comment: I believe the last command should be `openssl pkeyutl -verify -in hash.txt -sigfile sig.txt -inkey pub.pem -pubin`. You used the private key to verify it, but it should be the public one.